# How do you take position "x" in multiple sublists to make a new list?

Tags: list-manipulation

this is a rather rudimentary question, but I was wondering if there are more efficient ways to do the following:

```
dd = {{{12, 3, 5}, {14, 10, 11}}, {{15, 76, 65}}}
```

If I have list dd, I want identify alternative ways to pick out elements in each sublist that are in the same positions and make them into a new list.  For example, if I took out the first position of every sublist, I'd get the output:

```
Output={{12, 14}, {15}}
```

To make new output lists with the first/last element positions are the easiest and can be achieved through:

```
lis1 = Map[First, dd, {2}]
lis2 = Map[Last, dd, {2}]
```

However, to get an output where the "middle" position elements are taken and put into a new list (`{{3, 10}, {76}}`) I used:

```
lis3 = Map[Rest, dd, {2}]
lis4 = Map[First, lis3, {2}]
```

This seems like a rather roundabout way to obtain the desired list.  Would there be a more streamlined alternative which I can `Map` directly to list dd and avoid having to manipulating the list first (lis3)?

Comment: `Map[#[[k]]&, dd, {2}]` with your choice of `k`?

Comment: Or `Apply[#k &, dd, {-2}]`, e.g., `Apply[#2 &, dd, {-2}]`.

Comment: Is `dd[[ All, All, k ]]` what you need or did I miss something?

Comment: `dd/.{x_,y_,z_}:> y`

Answer (score 5):

```
k=2;
Map[#[[k]] &, dd, {2}]
```

> ```
>  {{3, 10}, {76}}
> ```

Also

```
Flatten[dd, {3}][[k]]
```

> ```
>  {{3, 10}, {76}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
dd = {{{12, 3, 5}, {14, 10, 11}}, {{15, 76, 65}}};
```

Using `Query`

First positions

```
Query[All, All, #[[1]] &] @ dd
```

{{12, 14}, {15}}

Middle positions

```
Query[All, All, #[[2]] &] @ dd
```

{{3, 10}, {76}}

Answer (score 1):

```
dd = {{{12, 3, 5}, {14, 10, 11}}, {{15, 76, 65}}};
```

---

Using `ReplaceAll` for the first positions:

```
dd /. x_?VectorQ :> First@x

(*{{12, 14}, {15}}*)
```

Middle positions:

```
dd /. x_?VectorQ :> x[[-2]]

(*{{3, 10}, {76}}*)
```